# Синхронизация с сервером в PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, sftp

Соединяюсь c сервером по SFTP в PhpStorm. Отправка файлов происходит автоматически при сохранении. Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы синхронизировать проект? Например, если я в консоли создам файл, то в PhpStorm проекте он не появится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете выбрать в дереве проекта нужную папку, в контекстном меню выбрать **Deployment | Sync with Deployed to** *server name*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm